# How to prevent Salesforce from changing the Case Owner when updating a field with C#

Tags: c#

I wrote a piece of code that updates some custom fields in several objects, however, when I am trying to update a custom field in Cases the Case Owner is changed to the one set up in Support Settings. This is a behaviour that I want to prevent from happening or avoid, to be able to update the custom field in cases. This is part of the code I have that updates the custom fields.

I also tried to get the previous ownerid and keep it in memory, however, when the update is executed something happens after that changes the owner.

The important thing here is that the case is already created and just want to update the custom fields nothing else.

```
    Dim client = New ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion)
    Dim SFCaseNumber As String = txtCustomerOrderNumber.Text
    Dim cases = Await client.QueryAsync(Of Cases)("SELECT id,RecordTypeId,OwnerId  FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '" & SFCaseNumber & "'")


    Dim SFCase = cases.Records.Single()
    Dim id As String = SFCase.Id.ToString()
    Dim OwnerId As String = SFCase.OwnerId.ToString()
    Dim RecordType As String = SFCase.RecordTypeId.ToString()

    //Once any of these lines are executed the field gets updated but the case owner is changed as well. Salesforce seems to be actioning something to set up the user in Support Settings. I just want to update the custom field and keep the original owner.
    Dim success = Await client.UpdateAsync(DealStart.Cases.SObjectTypeName, SFCase.Id, New With {Key .Total_Connected_GP__c = TotalConnectedGP})
    Dim success2 = Await client.UpdateAsync(DealStart.Cases.SObjectTypeName, SFCase.Id, New With {Key .No_of_Lines_Processed__c = TotalLines})
    Dim success3 = Await client.UpdateAsync(DealStart.Cases.SObjectTypeName, SFCase.Id, New With {Key .Tot_New_Mobile__c = TotalNew})
    Dim success4 = Await client.UpdateAsync(DealStart.Cases.SObjectTypeName, SFCase.Id, New With {Key .Tot_Resign_Mobile__c = TotalResign})
```

Is this possible? Any ideas will be welcome.

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this update occur when you change any of those fields in Salesforce itself, via UI or apex?

Comment: I'd suggest checking the debug log in Salesforce to see what other automation may be involved when a Case is updated.

Comment: Does this update occur when you change any of those fields in Salesforce itself, via UI or apex? No, it doesn't.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the debug log in Salesforce to see what other automation may be involved when a Case is updated. The Support Settings process is triggered and assigns the Default Case Owner.

Answer (score 0):

To handle this I created two flows.
1.- To record who the previous owner is/was.
2.- To revert back to previous owner when the criteria is met.

This solution is working but I prefer to handle this with the code.